# GNU Make not found - How to install GNU Make on 12.04

Tags: ruby, make, rvm

We have set up an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server for RoR. We did successfully install rvm and git. However installation failed with rvm for zlib and ruby 1.9.3. Here is the error log for `$rvm install 1.9.3`:

```
checking pthread.h presence... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking for if make is GNU make... ./configure: line 17125: make: command not found
```

The problem seems to be with GNU Make. Any solutions to fix? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 12):

```
$rvmsudo apt-get install make
```

solved the problem.